# How to define a data type from file in C++?

Tags: c++, casting, types

I'm making a class for an object that should contain a value, however the value is to be read externally in the form of VALUE, DATATYPE, where DATATYPE tells me how to interpret the given VALUE (int, float, double, char, etc).

I wonder if is possible to make the casting at run time and how to do it, to be honest I'm a bit lost and the information that I've found about the topic seems to bit a bit of an overkill.

Any ideas ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Look up discriminated unions and boost::variant in particular, but the gist is:

```
struct Value {
  enum { INT, FLOAT, DOUBLE, CHAR, ETC } type;
  union {
    int int_;
    float float_;
    double double_;
    char char_;
    etc etc_;
  } value;
};
```

Then you check the type before doing any operation, and select the right union member based on what has been stored in it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a map of "parsers" for each type. Parser could be a pointer to a function that accepts a string and returns a variant (see other answers). Something like this (untested pseudo-code):

```
class TypedReader {
  public:
    typedef Variant (*Parser)(const std::string &value);
    Variant readVariant(std::istream &in);
  private:
    std::map<std::string, Parser> parsers;
    // these parsers are added to the "parsers" field above by the constructor
    static Variant intParser(const std::string &value);
    static Variant doubleParser(const std::string &value);
    // and so on
};

Variant TypedReader::readVariant(std::istream &in) {
  // read next (type, value) pair
  std::map<std::string, Parser>::iterator i = parsers.find(type);
  if (i == parsers.end()) {
    // error, type not supported, throw exception or return an invalid variant
  } else {
    return (*i->second)(value);
  }
}
```

By an invalid variant I mean a special type that doesn't contain anything. It could be called an empty or a null variant too. As pointed out in the comments, the parsers field can be static too, but then it should be initialized in some static way. For example, it could be encapsulated in another class that has a default constructor.

Comment: If the identifying keys are fixed, the parsers member can be static, too.  Might be good to point out that by "invalid variant" you mean (I hope) adding another potential type to the variant to represent this (valid) state, such as adding "INVALID" to the enum in my answer.  But throwing an exception would be better if this state is otherwise unneeded.

Comment: @Fred, invalid variant is exactly what you said. Exceptions are a bit less portable, otherwise they are usually better. Invalid variants can have other uses too, similar to the uses of NULL pointers. Parsers member can be static indeed, haven't thought of that because I was modeling this example after one of my classes that supports dynamic registration of new types.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is a variant type. Start reading [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variant_type).

You could create a class which reads the data from file and stores it internally in a variant.

Answer (score 0):

The most extensible is abstract factory pattern.

```
typedef boost::function<Variant(istream&)> VariantFactory;
std::map< int, VariantFactory > variantFactoryTable;

Variant readVariantFromStream(istream& is)
{
   int type = 0;
   if( is >> type )
   {
       std::map<int, VariantFactory>::const_iterator factIter = 
          variantFactoryTable.find(type);

       if(factIter != variantFactoryTable.end() )
       {
           return factIter->second(is);
       }
       else
       {
           // handle error by throwing or returning a Null
       }
   }
   else
   {
       // handle EOS condition (probably not with exception)
   }
}
```